# Monaco-editor : Is there a way to prevent cursor/editor's focus from being lost on clicking outside the editor ( on blur )

Tags: monaco-editor, visual-studio-monaco, ngx-monaco-editor

Monaco-editor :- Is there a way to prevent cursor/editor focus from being lost on clicking outside the editor.

My scenario :- I have a list of items in a dropdown that is outside the editor , user can select a dropdown item and I am calling executeEdits to paste this selected item in the editor's previous cursor position.

When the user opens the dropdown the focus from the editor is lost, user is now not sure where his selected dropdown value will be inserted.

Is there a way in which I can prevent the editor from losing it's focus on blur. ?